# Theta notation for Strassen's multiplication

Tags: theta-functions

A student discovers a way to multiply 2×2 matrices using exactly 5 multiplications, instead of Strassen’s 7. What is the number M(n) of multiplications for the resulting algorithm to multiply n×n matrices? Use Θ-notation to express your estimate.

Comment: Students don't discover such things, nowadays. They ask at MSE how to multiply matrices (with all steps). Much as you do concerning $M(n)$, without _any_ own effort.